# OR operator in C not working

Tags: c

I don't understand why the final `printf` in the code below is not printing 255.

```
char c;
c = c & 0;
printf("The value of c is %d", (int)c);
int j = 255;
c = (c | j);
printf("The value of c is %d", (int)c);
```

Comment: What is it printing?  What happens if you change 'j' to be a char?

Comment: You don't need the casts (I hate casts). The compiler will automatically cast before calling `printf` provided it knows the parameter is part of the variable parameters in the function -- ie: provided you have `#include <stdio.h>` at a suitable place in your code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In most implementations the `char` type is signed, so it ranges from `-128` to `127`.

This means, `11111111` (which is `255` written in binary) is equal to `-1`. (As it's represented as a value stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

To get what you expect, you need to declare `c` as a `unsigned char`, like so:

```
unsigned char c = 0;
int j = 255;
c = (c | j);
printf("The value of c is %d", (int)c);
```

Comment: A `char` is signed on many implementations, but the C standard allows an implementation to have `char` unsigned as well.

Comment: @dreamlax: If the program above doesn't print `255`, then it clearly cannot be unsigned. :)

Comment: Of course, but your answer makes it seem like `char` can *only* be signed.

Comment: @dreamlax: Clarified, then. :)

Comment: The signedness of char is a very real issue these days (unlike, say, non-8-bit-bytes): the main platform on which `char` is unsigned is ARM. It's a pain if you're doing anything embedded.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably printing -1. That is because

```
c = (c | j);
```

will evaluate as

```
c = (0 | 255) = (0 | 0xFF) = 0xFF
```

but, since `c` is signed, `0xFF` will be -1 and not 255 as you expected. If you change `c` to `unsigned char` it will print 255, as you imagined.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `char c` with `unsigned char c`. Basically char type supports values from -128 to 127. Your result is bigger than the supported range and overflows.

Answer (score 0):

By default    `char`
 is     `signed char`
 in C. If you want     `255` to be printed then use      `unsigned char`
however i explain the output in context of     `signed char`
so that the concept becomes clear.
If you write     `j=127` then it will print      `127` as the bit representation is 01111111.
But if you write      `j=128`
 then it will print     `-128`
because the bit representation 01111111 has increased by 1 to become 10000000.
now if you write     `j=255`
then the bit representation is 11111111. so it will print      -1
If you write      `j=256` 
then it will print      `0`
because when bit representation 11111111 is increased by 1 it becomes 100000000. But only 1 byte is allocated for a characher variable so the left most bit is not stored and bit representation becomes 00000000. 
Further if you write      `j=257` 
then its also a case of overflow and the bit representation become 00000001 and      `1` will be printed.